trying to convert data from one data to another value from a different data frame
I have two dataframes df1 and df2, df2 has a list of zipcodes and their corresponding county FIPS codes. Df1 has a list of zipcodes. How do I create a new variable in df1 that matches participant zipcode to corresponding FIPS in df2 then inputs them back into df1.
For example:
df1: Participant X, zipcode 12345
df2: zipcode 12345 -> FIPS 678910

I want to create variable df1$fips based on df1$zipcode via df2 conversion.
I have tried the ifelse() function and match[] function but not sure how to make it go the additional step of converting that matched zipcode to the corresponding FIPS and then returning it to df1.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But data in a reproducible format like dput() so we can copy/paste the data into R for testing.
